# SQL query with a Matlab variable >> Error using ==> horzcat

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab variable:

```
Name     Size     Bytes     Class     
code     14x1     1036      cell
```

and I would like to pass the variable to a query in oracle

```
sqlstr = ['select * from sqltable where code in' (code)]
```

But I receive this error:

```
??? Error using ==> horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate a cell array with a string, so you'll need to actually convert the cell array of strings into a list of values for your query

```
code = {'one', 'two', 'three'};

array = ['(''', strjoin(code, ''','''), ''')'];
%   ('one','two','three')

sqlstr = ['select * from sqltable where code in ' array];
%   select * from sqltable where code in ('one','two','three')
```

Be sure to be careful what `code` contains if it's user-submitted since a carefully-crafted value could lead to a SQL injection.

```
code = {'one''); DROP TABLE users; select * from table where column in (''one'}
```

**Update**

If you don't have `strjoin`, you can instead do:

```
array = sprintf('''%s'', ', code{:});
array = ['(', array(1:end-2), ')'];
sqlstr = ['select * from sqltable where code in ' array];
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately I have Matlab 7.5.0 and the 'strjoin' function is not available

Comment: @NG83 Updated with an alternative